# Load json file, remove characters, and output new json file

Tags: json, python-3.x

I've got a JSON file with thousands of lines

```
[
   {
       "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"
   },
   {
       "text": "Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat"
   },
...
+1000 lines
]
```

and I'm trying to get this output

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
```

In order to load the JSON file, I'm using

```
import json

input_file=open('test.json', 'r')
output_file=open('formatted-test.json', 'w')
json_decode=json.load(input_file)
```

But I haven't managed to go through the JSON and remove the characters.
How can I achieve this?

I'm using Python 3.7.1

Comment: Example JSON you provided isn't really a JSON. Objects aren't enclosed in container (e.g. list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could iterate over the data and pull out the text:

```
as_text = [json_obj['text'] for json_obj in json_decode]
with open('test.txt', 'w+') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(as_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Provided you can afford entire content of input file in memory):

```
import json

with open('test.json', 'r') as in_f:
    content = in_f.read()
    data = json.loads(content)
    with open('formatted-test.json', 'w') as out_f:
        for datum in data:
            out_f.write(datum['text'] + '\n')
```